# 1st Dynamic Google maps API autocomplete.getPlace() returns null

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have 2 input boxes pickup and deliver. here is the library call:

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

and my autocomplete snipplet:

```
var inputStart = document.getElementsByClassName('ginput');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputStart.length; i++) {
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputStart[i]);
        console.log(autocomplete);
        autocomplete.inputId = inputStart[i].id;
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
        autocomplete.setFields(
        ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
        infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
        });
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
            infowindow.close();
            marker.setVisible(false);
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(place);
            if (!place.geometry) {
              // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
              // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
              window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
              return;
            }
            // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
              map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
            }
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);
            var address = '';
              //console.table(place);
            if (place.address_components) {
              address = [
                (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[6] && place.address_components[6].short_name || '')

              ].join(' ');
            }else{
                alert("No Place");
            }

            infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
            //infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
            infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

HTML:

```
<b>Pickup:</b>
<div id="pac-container-start">
<input id="pac-input-start" class="ginput" type="text"
    placeholder="Enter a pickup location">
</div>

<b>Dropoff:</b>
<div id="pac-container-end">
<input id="pac-input-end" class="ginput" type="text"
    placeholder="Enter a dropoff location">
</div>
```

The problem is after selecting an address from the dropdown, i get an error:

```
scripts.js:159 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined
```

I have logged out places and it is undefined, funny thing is when i select an address in the 2nd box, it seems to work fine. no errors, maps out the proper directions and all.
Almost seems to me like its confused on which box is sending the request?
Pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (read ***minimal*** and *complete*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your autocomplete is left on the last input, so it no longer works on the first.

One way to fix that would be to use `Array.prototype.forEach` to iterate through the input collection, giving function closure on each autocomplete instance:

```
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputStart, function(el, i) {
    console.log(inputStart[i].id);
    var autocomplete= new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputStart[i]);
    console.log(autocomplete);
    autocomplete.inputId = inputStart[i].id;
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    autocomplete.setFields(
      ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
    infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      marker.setVisible(false);
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log(place);
      if (!place.geometry) {
        // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
        // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
        window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
        return;
      }
      // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
      }
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
      marker.setVisible(true);
      var address = '';
      //console.table(place);
      if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
          (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[6] && place.address_components[6].short_name || '')

        ].join(' ');
      } else {
        alert("No Place");
      }

      infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
      //infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
      infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    })
  })
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/256a8ucd/7/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet**

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');

  var inputStart = document.getElementsByClassName('ginput');
  //for (var i = 0; i < inputStart.length; i++) {
  // inputStart.forEach(function() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputStart, function(el, i) {
    console.log(inputStart[i].id);
    var autocomplete= new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputStart[i]);
    console.log(autocomplete);
    autocomplete.inputId = inputStart[i].id;
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    autocomplete.setFields(
      ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);
    infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      marker.setVisible(false);
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log(place);
      if (!place.geometry) {
        // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
        // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
        window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
        return;
      }
      // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
      }
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
      marker.setVisible(true);
      var address = '';
      //console.table(place);
      if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
          (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[6] && place.address_components[6].short_name || '')

        ].join(' ');
      } else {
        alert("No Place");
      }

      infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
      //infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
      infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    })
  })
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 80%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.ginput {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
  <div id="pac-container">
    <input id="pac-input" class="ginput" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location" value="Potts Point">
    <input id="pac-input2" class="ginput" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location" value="Sydney">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap&v=quarterly"
        async defer></script>
```